# Can I prevent Qt to scan for plugin dlls?

Tags: performance, qt, plugins, build

I have a Qt application that is not intended to be extensible.  It does,
however, use Qt plugins to allow extra widgets and stuff.

At boot time, I see that the application scans all files in the application's directory to detect possible Qt plugin binaries.  This takes a lot of time when I run the app from the build output dir (which contains .lib, .pdb, .exp, .ilk, ... files, too).

My current solution is to build my app and its own plugins into a separate dir.  This alleviates the problem, but complicates the build.

Is there a way to directly tell Qt which dlls are to be loaded as plugins, and prevent it from scanning for additional plugins?